# Line numbering with memoir in Persian

Tags: numbering, memoir, right-to-left, persian

I'm typesetting Persian poems alongside their translations. It would be useful to have line numbers for this. I am using `memoir`, but now I came across an issue I cannot solve. The line number appear as wanted, but unfortunately they are written right to left instead of left to right, probably due to something babel does? Any suggestions for solving this?

```
  \documentclass[a5paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}
  \usepackage[LAE,T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[farsi,ngerman]{babel}
    
  \begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{farsi}
    \settowidth{\versewidth}{حریفا ! میزبانا ! میهمان سال و ماهت پشت در چون موج می لرزد} 
    \PoemTitle{زمستان}
    \begin{verse}[\versewidth]
        \linenumberfrequency{5}
        سلامت را نمی خواهند پاسخ گفت\\
        سرها در گریبان است\\
        کسی سر بر نیارد کرد پاسخ گفتن و دیدار یاران را\\
        نگه جز پیش پا را دید ، نتواند\\
        که ره تاریک و\\
        لغزان است\\
        وگر دست محبت سوی کسی یازی\\
        به اکراه آورد دست از بغل بیرون\\
        که سرما سخت سوزان است\\
        نفس ، کز گرمگاه سینه می آید برون ، ابری شود تاریک
    \end{verse}
  \end{document}
```

Without the additional `\selectlanguage`, the numbering starts before the title for some reason. The problem at hand now is this though: Line number 10 is numbered as "۰۱" while it should be "۱۰".
[image: Line number 10 is numbered as "۰۱" while it should be "۱۰".]